# Check for COM Object Collection Propertys Existence

Tags: vb6, outlook, nullreferenceexception

I have been pondering this one for a while.  I am programatically (in VB6) sifting through Outlook PSTs, indexing items that are in them.  I have happened on to one that is a little corrupted and this is where I am having difficulty.  My program attaches the PST and starts drilling down through the folders (olFolder).  These Outlook created objects are supposed to have a collection that would normally hold sub folders (appropriately named Folders).

During the execution of my code I recursively call the process folder function to process all folders in the current folder, but I have one that does not have a collection.  This causes an exception because I am checking the count of folders in the collection and there is nothing to check.  I understand how to check for the existence of an object, but I am having a hard time checking for the existence of a collection in and object.

### Update

The expression:

```
If Not fl.Folders Is Nothing Then
```

ends up throwing the exception too. The exception that I am getting is the following:

```
Could not complete the operation because the service provider does not support it.
```

This is only when trying to access this corrupted folder which appears to have a Folders Collection Property that is FUBARed.

### Final

Alright; in this case I am just going to put in some in-line error handling.

```
If Not Err.Number = -2147221246 Then
'Do the thing with the other thing
End If
Err.Clear
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about checking whether `obj.Coll.Count = 0`, then see if `obj.Coll Is Nothing`.

Comment: Hmmm.  I could have sworn that I tried exactly that and it threw an exception...  Well, Thank you very much for the help.  This is what I get for working early Saturday morning....

Comment: At first, it looked like that worked, but aparently I did try that, and it did not work.  I will add some more detail to my post above.

Comment: While this was not the answer in my case, I was working with a badly mangled PST file which Outlook was freaking out about, this would indeed been the way I would have done it had it been a more "normal" (Is there such a thing in development?) case.

Answer (score 0):

well when i work web services on vb6 i have check some cases if property exist. i used that method.

It is slow but i hope that help you.

```
Public Function HasProperty(ByRef obj As Object, ByVal nameProperty As String) As Boolean

On Local Error GoTo hasProperty_Error

   Dim Result

   Result = CallByName(obj, nameProperty, VbGet)

  hasProperty = True
hasProperty_Done:
  Exit Function

hasProperty_Error:
    If Err.Number = 438 Then
      hasProperty = False
    End If

Resume hasProperty_Done

End Function
```